# How to turn off wireless Access Point during the simulation in INET?

Tags: c++, omnet++

Is that possible to turn off a wireless node for example an Access Point during the simulation in Omnet++/Inet?

I've changed a number of parameters to VOLATILE for example inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint.numRadios and another time inet.physicallayer.base.packetlevel.NarrowbandTransmitterBase.power.

Here is the piece of code in c++ that changed the power parameter (it works):

```
inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211TransmitterBase *trMod = dynamic_cast<inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211TransmitterBase*>(mod);
cPar& po = trMod->par("power");
simtime_t sst=simTime();

if (msg == timeoutEvent) {
     if (sst>=3){                 
          po.setDoubleValue(0);
     }
     scheduleAt(simTime()+3.0, timeoutEvent);
}
```

But in practice the wireless hosts never disassociate from the AccessPoint in spite the fact that the transmitter.power is 0! Why? What should I do to power off the AP so that the wireless hosts disassociate?

Please somebody help me. I've tried so much to change the parameter in runtime and now I see that it doesn't work :(

Many thanks